# Number of $j-1$-dimensional subspaces containing $\textbf{1}$ in the binary field $\Bbb{F}_2^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

I have a $j$ dimensional vector space $V$ over $\Bbb{F}_2^n$ which contains the vector $\textbf{1}=(1,1,1,...,1)$.

I want to show that there are $2^{j-1} -1$ $(j-1)$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ which also contain the vector $\textbf{1}=(1,1,1,...,1)$.

I've been able to prove that there are $2^{j} -1$ total $(j-1)$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ via the usual method:
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2^{j}-1)(2^{j}-2)\dots(2^{j}-2^{j-2})}{(2^{j-1}-1)(2^{j-1}-2)\dots(2^{j-1}-2^{j-2})}.
\end{equation}

I'm not sure how to do this with the restriction that the subspaces must contain $\textbf{1}$.

Comment: The title refers to $(j-1)$-dimensional subspaces, but the body never mentions such subspaces. Also, since $V$ is itself $j$-dimensional, it has no $j$-dimensional subspaces. I suspect you meant to refer to $(j-1)$-dimensional subspaces in the body as well?

Comment: Also, you refer to “the binary field”, which is usually $\mathbb F_2$; your calculations seems to assume that there are $2$ scalars; the field with $2^n$ elements is usually denoted $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ and not $\mathbb F_2^n$ (though it’s isomorphic to $\mathbb F_2^n$ as a vector space over $\mathbb F_2$), and the variable $n$ doesn’t appear anywhere else in the question – all of this makes me suspect that perhaps you mean $\mathbb F_2$ where you wrote $\mathbb F_2^n$?

Comment: @joriki I'm working with binary vectors of length n. Sorry for the confusion; and yes I meant to write (j-1)-dimensional subspaces of V. I will fix this now.

Comment: I still don’t understand. If by $\mathbb F_2^n$ you’re referring to the vector space of binary vectors of length $n$ (which is the usual meaning of that notation), then why are you calling this “the binary field $\mathbb F_2^n$” and referring to a “vector space $V$ over $\mathbb F_2^n$” (where “over” implies that you’re viewing $\mathbb F_2^n$ as the field of scalars for the vector space $V$)? It seems to me that what you mean is the vector space $\mathbb F_2^n$, not a field, and that $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb F_2^n$ (over the field $\mathbb F_2$), not a vector space over $\mathbb F_2^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever $V$ is a vector space of dimension $m$ and $x\in V$ is a non-zero vector, spanning a $1$-dimensional subspace $L$, there is a bijective correspondence between
the set $S_1$ of $\ell$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ containing the vector $x$, and the set $S_2$ of $(\ell-1)$-dimensional subspaces of the $(m-1)$-dimensional quotient space $V/L$. The correspondence maps $U\in S_1$ to $U/L\in S_2$.

Comment: So if I find the number of 1-dimensional subspaces of V i.e. $2^{j-1}-1$, then this is also the number of $j-1$ dimensional subspaces of V which contain a given vector. Is that correct? Could you please tell me what this bijection is rule called. Thanks!

Comment: $\dim V/L=j-1$. And you want to count its $(j-2)$-dimensional subspaces. Yes, their number is equal to its $1$-dimensional subspaces, i.e. $2^{j-1}-1$.

Comment: A more general version of this result is aptly called [the correspondence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem).

Comment: The space $V$ has $2^j-1$ 1-dimensional subspaces. You want those of $V/L$.